# Phone 7 Bing map control - ManipulationStarted event not starting

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I created a regular Phone 7 template.
Drug the Bing map control to the main grid.
And for some reason the ManipulationStarted event is not fired when i click/interact with the bing map control in the emulator.

Why this is happening ?

(I am using latest Phone 7 Tools RTM).

Answer (score 1):

You need to track the Zoom and Pan events instead - I'm never seeing the ManipulationStarted event firing either.

Chris